# Studio BumbleBee "Render Problem" For Compose Preview

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I am unable to preview anything in Studio, extending to something as simple as a `Text`. I get a "Render Error", revealing this stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.<packageName>.Navigation_ComponentsKt.<PreviewName>
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.findComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:78)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:183)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:553)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:551)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:590)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:546)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:495)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:494)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:490)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:546)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:543)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3330)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:814)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:57)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:362)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This seems to be happening only since two to three updates earlier of the Bumblebee Studio, and it is causing much discomfort.

I just realised while asking that I should probably file this as an issue on the issuetracker, but now I have typed this question, and I AM NOT GOING TO WASTE THIS HARDWORK.

Jokes aside, if anyone has stumbled upon this before, and possibly has a fix, kindly share. Is this a known issue of AGP or some other component? Workarounds are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a code example

Comment: Well I already said that even a Text is not working. But if you want it explicitly, then this would be it. `Text("Hello World")`

Comment: I have Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1 and everything works fine. Why not using a stable understand of a Canary.

Comment: Canary has almost all features

Comment: If we wanted to learn compose for the past two years, the Canary build was our only option

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Step 1: Use latest version**

```
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
```

**Step 2: Set systemUi and showBackground**

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ModifierPreview() {

Text("hello world")
}
```

**Step 3: Run the application for first time.**

Without run the application it shows error. So first time run the app next time click refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rajnith, but I already am using the latest tooling, `1.0.1`

Comment: @MARSK try showSystemUi and background also. I also face same issue long time. Now only I solved using this

Comment: Sorry it's been so late for my response. Yeah the method is not working for me, but I think I might have found out the issue. I upgraded to Compose `1.0.1` while Studio still used `1.0.0`, and I think that's what could have caused the compatibility issue. Although, the tooling version being upgraded alongside the Compose version, and the fact that I know someone who is not facing this issue would argue otherwise. Anyway, thanks for the solution, but it didn't work for me specifically. PS: I didn't downvote

Comment: HEY HEY HEY!!!! I can't believe it worked. It wasn't working earlier, but I checked back and it was being displayed. Thanks man!!

Comment: It is strange now it is working even without those parameters. But like a day ago it wasn't. Not sure whether this happened by the parameter addition or some update, but anyway it worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **different version** of androidx tooling in your build.gradle file 
`implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-rc01"`
If it doesn't work try different version which works for you

Comment: You see the tooling library updates alongside compose. Hence its version numbers are the same as their compose version. This is a part of the defaults, and I do not think modifying these values is the correct way to do this, since it might evoke some compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix**

Use Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1. It's now stable and supports Compose.

I've tested this Composable and it works fine:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String = "") {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

Any questions left? Just comment.

**See also**

If you want to you can enable "Interactive and animation preview tools". It's under Settings -> Enable Interactive and animation preview tools

This allows you to instantly see the changes you made without building. This works only for some some basic types like strings and integers

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to preview by trying to retrieve data from my ViewModel, which was causing the issue.

I was doing this:

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
  Catalog(
    viewModel.getSomeData() // Don't do this!
  ) 
}
```

The key challenge here was the use of [Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html) for dependency injection. Hilt injects ViewModels at runtime, but Compose previews are generated at compile time, leading to a "view not found" error because the ViewModel isn't available.

**The solution is: avoid directly accessing the ViewModel in the preview function. For previews, use static data or mock the necessary data instead.**