# Preview java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeKt.fillMaxWidth$default

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

I started migrate our code to Compose and have problem with @Preview.
For example, when I use `modifier.fillMaxWidth()` without default param "fraction = 1f" I have render problem

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'androidx.compose.ui.Modifier androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeKt.fillMaxWidth$default(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, java.lang.Float, int, java.lang.Object)'

or use padding without bottom param

```
.padding(
    top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._4sdp),
    start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16sdp),
    end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16sdp)
)
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'androidx.compose.ui.Modifier androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingKt.padding-qDBjuR0$default(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp, androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp, androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp, androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp, int, java.lang.Object)'

here the code I use

```
@Composable
fun Info(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    step: String,
    stepInfo: String,
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(fraction = 1f)) {
        Text(
            text = step,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.color_on_background_variant3),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(90)
                )
                .size(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._28sdp))
                .padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._6sdp))
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = stepInfo,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._4sdp),
                    start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16sdp),
                    end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16sdp),
                    bottom = 0.dp
                )
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Preview(uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES, name = "InfoPreviewNight")
@Composable
fun InfoPreview() {
    MdcTheme {
        Info(
            step = "1",
            stepInfo = ".............."
        )
    }
}
```

buidld.gradle (:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.1'
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime"
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation"
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout"
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata"
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
        implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-themeadapter-material:0.30.1"
        debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
        androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    }
```

> Gradle Plugin Version  ------    7.2.2
> Gradle Version  -------   7.3.3

I tried change kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion but I got no result
and [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621868/studio-bumblebee-render-problem-for-compose-preview) didn't helped.

Comment: Are you tried with latest compose bom version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping

Comment: @Srimani789 thx, but didn't helped

Comment: i executed the above code and got the preview without any issue. compose bom `2023.06.01`, compose compiler `1.4.1`, kotlin version `1.8.0` and gradle `8.0`

Comment: Also having this same error message. I've tried reproducing this in a new project but have not had any luck yet. I was thinking this was a conflicting import issue, but after importing all of our imports into a new project the issue did not appear. @Srimani789 Using all of the same versions you mentioned, all except gradle which were on 7.5.1. but the issue remains.

Comment: @Ihor Some of the compose imports you have in your project are unnecessary, many are embedded in `androidx.compose.material:material`. Check out this compose setup guide for more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Comment: Also worth noting that I've been able to side step this issue by rebuilding my project and my previews build just fine. Its only when it tried to recompile the preview without rebuilding the project that the preview fails to build, such as updating a displayed text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Android Studio to  Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1 version, the broblem has gone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I upgraded the Compose compiler to latest version and now the preview works properly again.

in build.gradle

```
composeOptions {
    //find latest compiler version here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.5.3"
    kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
}
```

Comment: good idea, but for me helped updated android studio, and i dont want try others solutions while it works :)